# Rails - Inserting Variables inside an image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a dynamic image_tag url. Here is what I have

```
<%= image_tag('#{::Rails.root.to_s}/member.gif?id=#{@member.id}&d=#{@dog,id}') %>
```

But it's not rendering with the actual vars, it's rendering exactly as above.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you are using single quotes. Try this instead:

```
<%= image_tag("#{::Rails.root.to_s}/member.gif?id=#{@member.id}") %>
```

The #{} operator won't be executed inside of single quoted strings.

To answer a question in the comments, to mark a string as html safe, meaning that HTML special characters should not be escaped, you can use the raw or html_safe functions:

```
"#{::Rails.root.to_s}/member.gif?id=#{@member.id}".html_safe
raw "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/member.gif?id=#{@member.id}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why & is rendering as &amp; and not & ?

Comment: Hey, I was about to answer with you should be using "my string".html_safe to mark your string as safe HTML, but I don't see an ampersand in your code.

Comment: I've updated my code with an example for making strings HTML safe.

Comment: Thanks but even with html_safe, the & is still be rendered as &amp;

Comment: The ampersand character has to be escaped according to the HTML standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/PR-html40-971107/charset.html

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, is the image not showing up? Did you try both raw("...") and "...".html_safe? Are you just trying to dispay this string in HTML? If so, then you will see &amp; in the source code for an & to appear on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes, inside single quotes there is no variables processing.